# F# equivalent to sending message to all actors in the system AKKA

Tags: functional-programming, f#, akka, akka.net, f#-interactive

What is the F# equivalent to the following code using AKKA.

```
context.system.actorSelection("/user/master/*")
```

Basically want to know how to send a message to all actors in the system by using f# and AKKA framework.

Comment: That code is valid F# syntax, you can use it without changes.